# Convert XML to CSV

Tags: c#, linq, csv, xml

I'm pretty sure this code can be optimized, but I'm not talented enough in Linq to do it myself. Here's what I'm trying to do: I have an XML file that needs to be converted into a .csv file. The XML looks like this:

```
<Inventory>
    <Item>
        <Name>Super Mario Bros</Name>
        <Count>14</Count>
        <Price>29,99</Price>
        <Comment>-No Comment-</Comment>
        <Artist>N/A</Artist>
        <Publisher>Nintendo</Publisher>
        <Genre>Video Games</Genre>
        <Year>1985</Year>
        <ProductID>001</ProductID>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Name>The Legend of Zelda</Name>
        <Count>12</Count>
        <Price>34,99</Price>
        <Comment>-No Comment-</Comment>
        <Artist>N/A</Artist>
        <Publisher>Nintendo</Publisher>
        <Genre>Video Games</Genre>
        <Year>1986</Year>
        <ProductID>002</ProductID>
    </Item>
</Inventory>
```

(There are many more Items in the list, but they are all the same.)

The code I'm currently using is working as intended, here it is:

```
public void fileConvert_XMLToCSV() {
    //This method converts an xml file into a .csv file

    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(FilePath_CSVToXML);
    StringBuilder dataToBeWritten = new StringBuilder();

    var results = xDocument.Descendants("Item").Select(x => new {
        title = (string)x.Element("Name"),
        amount = (string)x.Element("Count"),
        price = (string)x.Element("Price"),
        year = (string)x.Element("Year"),
        productID = (string)x.Element("ProductID")
    }).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++) {
        string tempTitle = results[i].title;
        string tempAmount = results[i].amount;
        string tempPrice = results[i].price;
        string tempYear = results[i].year;
        string tempID = results[i].productID;

        dataToBeWritten.Append(tempYear);
        dataToBeWritten.Append(";");
        dataToBeWritten.Append(tempTitle);
        dataToBeWritten.Append(";");
        dataToBeWritten.Append(tempID);
        dataToBeWritten.Append(";");
        dataToBeWritten.Append(tempAmount);
        dataToBeWritten.Append(";");
        dataToBeWritten.Append(tempPrice);
        dataToBeWritten.Append(";");
        dataToBeWritten.Append(0);
        dataToBeWritten.Append(";");
        dataToBeWritten.Append(0);
        dataToBeWritten.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(dataToBeWritten.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();

    var testpath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"frMediaShop\test.csv";

    File.WriteAllText(testpath, dataToBeWritten.ToString());
}
```

Running this method outputs a file (test.csv) that looks just like I want it. But the code is repetitive and dull. Please help me optimize it.

Comment: Instead of working the format translation manually, I recommend you to look into existing libraries. You will be surprised how many details exist even for such a simple format as CSV... Why taking all this burden? Somebody has done all the hard work for you. I'd look into this library: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, I'd split the convert method out into it's own thing - separate from the loading and saving:

```
// Load xml
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(FilePath_CSVToXML);

// Convert
string data = Convert(xDocument);

// Do whatever it is you want to do with the results
Console.WriteLine(data);
Console.ReadLine();

var testpath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"frMediaShop\test.csv";

File.WriteAllText(testpath, data);
```

We can simplify the actual conversion by using [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn961160.aspx) and rolling it all up in a single LINQ statement:

```
    private static string Convert(XDocument xDocument)
    {
        var data = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var result in xDocument.Descendants("Item").Select(x => new {
            title = (string)x.Element("Name"),
            amount = (string)x.Element("Count"),
            price = (string)x.Element("Price"),
            year = (string)x.Element("Year"),
            productID = (string)x.Element("ProductID")
        }))
        {
            data.AppendLine($"{result.year};{result.title};{result.productID};{result.amount};{result.price};{0};{0}");
        };

        return data.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This is an interasting casing _LinQ_ ;-)

Comment: Yeah, dunno where that came from!

Comment: @Pj. - Wouldn't it be better to create the string in the select statement, rather than creating anonymous objects first?

Comment: Although seperating the steps like this does increase readability, it causes the full document to be loaded into memory multiple times (As an XDocument, as a StringBuilder and as a string) which would cause significant issues if the file is large.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the values contain spaces so to make the csv file more robust and easier to read you should quote them or just everything. I also noticed that your csv does not contain the header row. Is there a reason for that?

I suggest using a more generic approach with some more linq that will first extract header names and then the values. Everything is joined together with the `Aggregate` extension that uses a `StringBuilder` initialized with the header and then appends each line to it.

```
var headers =
    xDocument
        .Descendants("Item")
        .First()
        .Elements().Select(e => e.Name.LocalName);

var delimiter = ";";

var entries =
    xDocument
        .Descendants("Item")
        .Select(d => string.Join(delimiter, d.Elements().Select(e => $"\"{e.Value}\"")))
        .Aggregate(
            new StringBuilder().AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, headers)), 
            (current, next) => current.AppendLine(next));

var csv = entries.ToString();
```

There is no need to hardcode the field names.

Comment: looks great, but hard to understand....

Comment: @t3chbot It works great when you have nice and tidy XML elements repeat in sequence. +1 for the way you use LINQ

Comment: Problem with this is what if you don't have data for every element. It will throw off the csv.

Comment: @user890332 probably yes... as always, reviews are just examples and usually not production-ready code ;-]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a series of Regex.Replaces:

```
// 1) Replace closing and opening tags with commas.
//    Include quotes in case any values have commas in them.
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\S)<\/[^>]*>\s*<[^>]*>(\S)", "$1\",\"$2");

// 2) Put in CSV line breaks and remove xml delimiters, include leading and trailing quotes
result = Regex.Replace(result, @"<\/[^>]*>\s*<\/Item>\s*<Item>\s*<[^>]*>", "\r\n");

// 3) Remove remaining tags and trim any whitespace
result = Regex.Replace(result, @"\s*<.*>\s*", "");

// 4) put in header row and first and last quotes
result = "Name,Count,Price,Comment,Artist,Publisher,Genre,Year,ProductID,\r\n\"" + 
         result + "\"";
```

is this a better solution than other solutions?  No.  It's brittle and would break easily.

Here are the Regex steps visually:

1. https://regex101.com/r/2jmvhc/1
2. https://regex101.com/r/0XyvZe/1
3. https://regex101.com/r/Sj6GsP/1

Comment: Gave this plus one even though this is clearly not advisable but for the great regex example.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several issues, which may or may not apply to your case.

- You don't sanitize any of the input, so if for example one of the XML tags contains a semicolon or a new line character you will end up with invalid CSV.
- You load the whole document into memory (the XDocument) and then aggregate all the output into memory before writing it to a file.

I suggest a streaming approach using `XmlReader` and C# iterators. The example I'm giving below is more efficient, but may be too complex for the task you require (small files).

**First the reader and converter**

```
class InventoryItem 
{
    // Properties for title, amount, price, year, etc..
}

private IEnumerable<InventoryItem> LoadInventoryItemsFromXML(string xmlFile) 
{
    // Open the source XML file
    using (var stream = new FileStream(xmlFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream)) 
    {
        // Read each of the tags
        // MoveToContent skips any whitespace and comments that may reside in the XML

        reader.MoveToContent();
        reader.ReadStartElement(); // Inventory
        reader.MoveToContent();

        while (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement(); // Item

            // Read the individual properties of the inventory item
            var item = new InventoryItem();
            while (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                // You could use a switch, possibly a dictionary if the amount of fields increase
                // Or you could use reflection
                switch (reader.LocalName)
                {
                    case "Name":
                        item.Name = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        break;

                    case "Count":
                        item.Count = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
                        break;

                    // etc.  

                    // Skip any unkown properties
                    default:
                      reader.Skip();
                      break;
                }
            }

            reader.ReadEndElement(); // Item

            yield return item;
        }

        reader.ReadEndElement(); // Inventory
    }
}
```

**Then write result out to CSV**

```
private void WriteInventoryItemsToCSV(string csvFile, IEnumerable<InventoryItem> items)
{
    // Open the output CSV file
    using (var stream = new FileStream(csvFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) 
    {
        // Loop through each of the items we read from the source CSV file.
        foreach (var item in items) 
        {
            writer.Write(CSVEscape(item.Title));
            writer.Write(';');

            // Asumming Amount and Price are numbers, we know they won't contain semicolons.
            // This means we don't have to escape them.
            writer.Write(item.Amount);
            writer.Write(';');
            writer.Write(item.Price);          
            writer.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}

// This methods escapes a string using quotes
private string CSVEscape(string str) 
{
    // Surround content in quotes and replace any quotes inside the string
    // with two double quotes
    return "\"" + str.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
}
```

**Then you can call this where you need it**

```
var items = LoadInventoryItemsFromXML(FilePath_CSVToXML);
WriteInventoryItemsToCSV(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"frMediaShop\test.csv", items);
```